# Setter method dont have any effect when bean scope changed to 'prototype'

Tags: spring

I have following classes defined in spring project

### Triangle.java

```
public class Triangle 
{

    private double breadth;
    private double length;

    public double getBreadth() {
        return breadth;
    }

    public void setBreadth(double breadth) {
        this.breadth = breadth;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

Below class calculates the area of triangle

### Area.java

```
public class Area 
{
    Triangle triangle;

    public Triangle getTriangle() {
        return triangle;
    }

    public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }

    public double triArea()
    {
        return (triangle.getBreadth() * triangle.getLength())/2;
    }
}
```

spring.xml configuration file is shown below

### spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd
/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="src.jayant.spring.Triangle" scope="prototype">
        <property name = "breadth" value = "20"/>
        <property name = "length" value = "20"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="area" class="src.jayant.spring.Area">
        <property name = "triangle" ref="triangle"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Finally we have AreaApp.java which gets both 'area' and 'triangle' beans defined in the xml and calculates the area.

### AreaApp.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;                                                                                           

public class AreaApp 
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        Triangle triangle = (Triangle)context.getBean("triangle");
        Area area = (Area)context.getBean("area");

        System.out.println("Area of Triangle is : "+area.triArea());

        triangle.setBreadth(40);

        System.out.println("Area of Triangle is : "+area.triArea());
    }
}
```

Now

When we have 'triangle' bean scope as 'singleton'

```
<bean id="triangle" class="src.jayant.spring.Triangle" scope="singleton">
```

then output will be

```
Area of Triangle is : 200.0
Area of Triangle is : 400.0
```

but when I change scope to 'prototype'

```
<bean id="triangle" class="src.jayant.spring.Triangle" scope="prototype">
```

then output will be

```
Area of Triangle is : 200.0
Area of Triangle is : 200.0
```

Why the setter method

```
triangle.setBreadth(40);
```

have no effect when bean scope is prototype.

Thanks

Jay

Answer (score 3):

It does have an effect: it changes the breadth of the triangle you got from the context.

But this triangle is not the same triangle as the one used by the `Area` bean, since your triangle bean is now a prototype, and thus, by definition of the prototype scope, you get a new instance every time you ask a Triangle instance to the context.

Comment: What I understood is triangle bean is injected by <bean id="triangle" class="src.jayant.spring.Triangle" scope="prototype"> and the very same bean is used in area as it is referenced using 'ref' in <property name = "triangle" ref="triangle"/> in bean area. How come a new triangle bean is created?

Comment: Because its scope is "prototype". The whole point of the prototype scope is to tell Spring that, every time the bean is requested from the context or injected in another bean, a **new** instance is created. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Comment: It's called once when Spring sets the triangle of the Area bean, based on `<property name = "triangle" ref="triangle"/>`. And it's called a second time when you call getBean().

Comment: What I ve understood till now is Triangle bean is only created once with because getBean("triangle") called only once. Do you wanted to say that a new Triangle bean creation take place every time it is used anywhere ?

Comment: No. what I mean is what I said in the previous comment, and what is explained in the official documentation that I linked to. Have you seen the big image saying "A brand new bean instance is created... each and every time the prototype is referenced by collaborating beans", and showing a piece of XML similar to the one you're using in your code?

Comment: Yes got it now. Thanks for your replies JB Nizet.